# Read CSV using pandas with values enclosed with double quotes and values have comma in column

Tags: python, csv

I need to read a file in python pandas of the following type

```
"column1","column2","column3","column4"
"value1","value,1","value2","value3"
"value5","value6","value7","value8"
"value32","value21","value,31","value,44"
```

I tried using

```
file1 = pd.read_csv('sample.txt',sep=',\s+',skipinitialspace=True,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,engine=python)
```

it says something like **ValueErro(Expected some lines got something else )** not exactly

I need to read a large CSV file of this type and load it to dataframe. what changes should i make to read it correctly.

Comment: I think you need to use `sep=',\s*'` instead of `sep=',\s+'`. As about comma inside quoted value (as it is a case for `"value,31"`) it comply with rfc4180 and shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Earlier it was showing**ValueError('Expected 1 fields in line 328, saw4',) **and after changing it to * it shows **ValueError('Expected 1 fields in line 328, saw6',)**

Comment: It looks like the issue with source data. Check that line 328 in source data file

Comment: I am sorry i haven't mentioned about that, I have checked it and found that there is an extra comma inside double quotes. i removed it manually and the code works fine. But i cannot do this all time, how can I change code to handle the situation.
There is another problem that inside the double quotes for one value there was another " " it also make the program to exit.

Comment: comma inside double quotes is Ok. As about `" "` - you need to clean up source file before processing. If double quotes stay together as `""` it shouldn't be an issue too because it comply with CSV standard, it calls escaped double quotes. If there is a space between  double quotes then run `sed -r 's/\"\s+\"/\"\"/g' src.csv >cleared.csv` before you feeding CSV to pandas. It will remove space between quotes or run `sed -r 's/\"\s+\"//g' src.csv >cleared.csv` to remove internal quotes completely

Comment: Thanks @Alex, i cleaned the data data and now it works well. Thanks for the sed.

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help you. I summarized everything in answer, so may be someone will find it helpful too

Comment: single quote is missing `pd.read_csv( ...... engine='python')`

Answer (score 4):

No need to preprocess csv file, just use engine type python :

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep=',', engine='python')
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, I'm still seeing single quotes in my dataframe.

Comment: @DataGirl try adding `skipinitials = True` to your `pd.read_csv(...)`. As you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37076344/3286178

Comment: As pointed out by @rwenz3l, but the syntax is `dataset = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep=',', skipinitialspace=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Use in python pandas `sep=',\s*'` instead of `sep=',\s+'`, it will make space(s) optional after each comma:

```
file1 = pd.read_csv('sample.txt',sep=',\s*',skipinitialspace=True,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,engine='python')
```

Comma inside double quotes is Ok, it's allowed by rfc4180 standard.
As about `" "` inside of data values (such as "value" "13") - you will need to clean up source file before processing. If double quotes stay together as "" it shouldn't be an issue because it comply with CSV standard, it calls escaped double quotes, but if there is a space between double quotes then you need to clean it up

Use:

```
sed -r 's/\"\s+\"/\"\"/g' src.csv >cleared.csv
```

before you feeding CSV to pandas. It will remove space between quotes or run

```
sed -r 's/\"\s+\"//g' src.csv >cleared.csv
```

to remove internal quotes completely.

Comment: Alex, where do you run sed -r 's/\"\s+\"//g' src.csv >cleared.csv?  Is this a command line piece of code?

Comment: @DataGirl Yes it should be run from command line, in terminal on Unix base system or if you on Windows then you need to install cygwin to use "sed" program

Comment: sep=',\s*' seems to break using quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL

Comment: single quote is missing `pd.read_csv( ...... engine='python')`

Comment: Fixed. Tnx Dipankar

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the argument `quotechar='"'` which helps ignore delimiters within the qutoes.

```
file1 = pd.read_csv('sample.txt',sep=',\s+', quotechar='"')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the only answer which directly addresses the issue and actually works, and without needing to preprocess the file outside.

Answer (score 0):

I "think" these two commands, with single quotes and double quotes between the file name, should work the same way (or not?):

pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

or this

pd.read_csv("filename.csv")

Comment: yes, but this isn't related to the question